# How do I open a specific location and not just address on tap in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift

**I am wondering if it is possible to direct to a specific page, ie. Whitney Museum of Art Page on Apple Maps, and not just it's address.** I have looked at other posts but they only reference the coordinates or the address, but not the location itself. For example tapping the text above redirects to 99 Gansevoort St in NYC, (Whitney Museum of American Art) but doesn't go to the landmark page as if you were to search Whitney Museum on Apple Maps and direct on the Museum page. **Is there any way to go directly to the page with the name not just the address.**
I included 2 photos below to clarify, the one above what the code below does and the other what I would like it to do. Right now I can go to a specific address on tap like so:

```
Text("Whitney Museum of Art"
    .onTapGesture {
                     UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "http://maps.apple.com/?address=99,GansevoortSt.,10014")!)
                    }
```

[image: What I have right now.]

[image: What I'd like to happen.]

Comment: I think you might be able to use `MKMapItem` and its `openMaps` function. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapitem and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapitem/1452239-openinmaps

Answer (score 0):

All right, I did some digging. If you press the share link in the address or the three more dots on Mac it copies a link to your clipboard. Then just using that as the URL will work. For example on my Mac I found MoMa's URL as: https://maps.apple.com/?address=11%20W%2053rd%20St,%20New%20York,%20NY%20%2010019,%20United%20States&auid=7324342225941186006&ll=40.761476,-73.977513&lsp=9902&q=The%20Museum%20of%20Modern%20Art&_ext=ChkKBQgEEOIBCgQIBRADCgQIBhAQCgQIChABEiYpwWW6beZgREAx8svcEPF+UsA5PzvgyQxiREBBWNN5wC5+UsBQBA%3D%3D&t=m